# Draw a siemens star in opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, drawing

I'm new in opencv. I should implement a siemens star (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Siemens_star.svg) in c++ and opencv. After days of searching the internet I'm very frustrated and I hope you can help me. I don't know how to start. My first idea to realize it, is to draw filled triangles from center and crop them with a circle. But I think there are no functions in opencv to draw a triangle. My 2nd approach is to plot all points between two vectors, but my mathematical knowledge is very poor (like my english, sorry ;)). 
Pleaseeee help me..

Thanks!

Comment: triangles work but it's harder to compute all the coordinates than just using the ellipse function to draw arc pieces (circular sectors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is how you can do it with `cv::ellipse` :

```
cv::Mat siemensStar(unsigned int radius, unsigned int number_of_pieces)
{
    // create output image
    cv::Mat star(2*radius, 2*radius, CV_8UC1, 255);

    // center in the middle of the image
    cv::Point2f center(radius,radius);

    // angle of a single arc (mind that there is always one black and one white arc
    float angle = 360.0f/(2*(float)number_of_pieces);

    // draw all arcs
    for(float i=0; i<360; i+=2*angle)
    {
        // draw the outlines anti-aliased or change the line type if you want
        cv::ellipse(star, center, cv::Size(radius,radius), 0, i, i+angle, cv::Scalar(0),-1, CV_AA);
    }

    return star;
}
```

this works and gives me with the call `cv::imshow("siemens star", siemensStar(256,16));` this result:

[image]

beware that this might not be what you want (since the optical effect in the center isnt really visible), but thats the problem of rastering (during drawing) I think. We don't work with vector images here. Maybe better if the number of elements is reduced...

Comment: hej Micka! Thanks for your reply! Thats is what I'm looking for. I have made it now also with ellipse() (thanks also to herohuyongtao!) but a little bit different..Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`ellipse()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse) to draw a group of filled ellipse sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong, there is a function to draw a triangle: `fillPoly`. You could have found that by simply googling "OpenCV draw".